# Printing from my Web App to a Zebra Printer (label printer) messing up style

Tags: html, css, printing, label, zebra-printers

Im trying to print labels I create dynamically in my web app to a zebra printer.

The problem is that the zebra printer messes up the style.
The first one looks good but then the second one starts coming out weird, and the third worst and so on.
Im trying to make them 4 x 6 inches.

Here is the style.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font: 6pt "Tahoma";
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page{
    width: 8.0in;
    min-height: 4in;
    padding: 8mm;
    margin: 21mm auto;
    border: 1px #CCD6E0 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       }
.subpage {
    padding: 2mm;
    border: 3px #718DA9 solid;
    height: 3.7in;
    outline: .5cm #CCD6E0 solid;
}


  @media print {
    html, body {
        width: 6in;
        height: 4in;        
    }
    .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE TABLE

Comment: Is having width: 6in in @media print (html,body) and width 8in in .page what you intended ?

Comment: How do you generate labels?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution, please post it here. Thanks

Comment: So this has been long time and I totally forgot about the question, what we did was convert the HTML to PDF made the sizes absolutes and then print them on the label.

Comment: @SuiGn Please add this as a solution.